# How to extend scalatest assert macro

Tags: scala, macros, scalatest

I would like to turn:

```
eventually { assert(x == 0) }
```

into:

```
verify { x == 0 }
```

and still get a nice console message:

```
Caused by: org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: 1 did not equal 0
```

How to implement `verify`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`verify` must be a macro, too:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

class VerifyMacro(val c: blackbox.Context) {
  import c.universe._

  def verifyImpl(condition: Tree): Tree =
    q"${c.prefix}.eventually(${c.prefix}.assert($condition))"
}

import org.scalatest._
import org.scalatest.concurrent._

trait Verifications extends Assertions with Eventually {
  def verify(condition: Boolean): Assertion = macro VerifyMacro.verifyImpl
}
```